# Union Find - Why we are checking Size for Weighted Quick Union

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, union-find

I was going through Princeton's Algorithms course on Coursera.

In the Union find section, for Weighted Quick union, we merge trees depending upon which tree is smaller in terms of **Size**.

[image]

However, I don't understand that why are we using **Size** rather than **Depth** to decide which tree is larger and which is smaller.

Wouldn't the Worst case time complexity of finding root increase because of tree **Depth**?

[image]

In the above example, if we merge the 2 trees by checking **size**, the **depth** of resulting tree is 4 whereas on checking by depth we get a smaller resulting tree depth.

Comment: both union by size or by depth results in O(log n) so you can use either. You can read more about this here: https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/disjoint_set_union.html#toc-tgt-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very common to use "rank" instead of size for the weighting.  Height is not used, because the height of a tree can be changed by path compression in ways that are difficult to track.  The rank of a tree is what the height would be if path compression wasn't in use.

Using the size of the tree, however, works just as well as rank -- the worst case complexities of union and find remain the same -- and is just as easy to track.  Furthermore, the size of each set can be a useful thing to know!  For that reason, I prefer weighting by size instead of rank.

Comment: I don't understand how they can be the same time complexity. Aren't we trying to reduce time complexity of finding the root by avoiding tall trees. As i explained in above image, union by size is resulting in taller trees.

Moreover size doesn't affect anything here. We could have a trees with size 1000 but depth 2 which would have a very good time complexity.

Comment: There is no sequence of union-by-size operations that could produce your chain-of-3 example.  There will be no "tall trees"